# Typescript project not outputting folder in correct folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

In my type script project I have this tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "lib": [
            "ESNext", "DOM"
        ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/",
        "src/**/*.json"
    ],
    "exclude": [

    ]
}
```

And I have my source folder like this

[image]

After I run `tsc`, I get

[image]

Basically the subfolders `js`, `json`, `units` don't get put in the `data` in `dist`, yet its in the `data` folder in `src`. How can I fix this?

Note: I have a separate program (`copyfiles`) creating the `data` folder with images, but that is working and irrelevant to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

see if adding root directory config in tsconfig solves it

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "lib": [
            "ESNext", "DOM"
        ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/",
        "src/**/*.json"
    ],
    "exclude": [

    ]
}
```